# Connection to <hostname>:5432 refused

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm not a pro in communication networks, so I have no idea what should be my "hostname" and where can I find it?

I created a postgreSQL server on ubuntu 14.04, I can connect to it from the same computer without problem by setting hostname to 127.0.0.1(localhost), or even 192.168.1.42 (my private ip). But I can not connect to my server from any other computer, even if they are on local network or not. I always get this message:

```
"Connection to <hostname>:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections."
```

where  is either 127.0.1.1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.42, 98.765.432.123(public ip) or anything else, it never works. 
What is the right hostname?

I already set listen_addresses to '*', already edited pg_hba.conf to accept 0.0.0.0/0 IP-s, and disabled ubuntu firewall.

Comment: can you post the jdbc connection string?

Comment: It's quite possible that you have a firewall in place that prevents connections from outside.

Comment: Giovanni, yes, "jdbc:postgresql://<hostname>/<dbname>" (inside < > are string variables, I input them with JTextField to my program)

Comment: What happens when you `telnet hostname 5432` ?  If that doesn't work, it's really a network problem, not a Postgres or JDBC problem.

Comment: Andomar, from which computer, my own (ubuntu), or from other (windows) computer in local/-non-local network? And hostname is what, my public IP ? (I'm not a pro). From my computer telnet works for 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.42, but not for public ip 98.765.432.123 (?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be caused by many things.

1. The server has an IP address. That is the address that the JDBC connection string should use for `<hostname>`, unless you have some local DNS solution. To rule out problems with the latter, use the IP address of the Ubuntu server. On Ubuntu type `ifconfig` to see it; it probably is `192.168.1.42` like you mentioned. **So from the client with the Java app, you use the IP address of the server.**
2. If you have a standard PostgreSQL installation, it should use port 5432, you can check the setting in `postgresql.conf`. In the JDBC connection string you should also indicate the port: "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.42:5432/...", just to be on the safe side.
3. You need to have a database that you can connect to. Note that by default only the owner of the database (probably the user `postgres` in your case) can connect to it. See further down.
4. In `pg_hba.conf` you need to create an entry for your new database so it can be connected to (typical settings, check your network setup). **The IP address (range) you specify here is that of the clients connecting to the database!**

   `host my_db all 192.168.0.0/16 md5`

You must restart your PostgreSQL server after modifying `pg_hba.conf`. (Typically on Ubuntu, do `sudo ./etc/init.d/postgresql restart`)

To create database `my_db` (or whatever name you prefer), go to your Ubuntu box and enter `psql` as the `postgres` user:

```
vekszor@ubuntu:~$ sudo -u postgres psql
[sudo] password for user:
psql (9.3.5)
Type "help" for help

postgres=#
```

In order to connect to the database, you should have a database:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE my_db;
CREATE DATABASE
```

You also want a user (role) that is less powerful than the `postgres` superuser, but still able to manipulate the database. So create this user role and assign ownership of the database:

```
postgres=# CREATE ROLE vekszor LOGIN PASSWORD 'secret123' CREATEROLE;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# ALTER DATABASE my_db OWNER TO vekszor;
ALTER
```

Now you can go back to your client computer with the Java app and finish the JDBC connection string with the name of the database, the user and password.

Note that if you want to access your database from the internet, you should set up a NAT rule in your router to point traffic on port 5432 to the IP of your Ubuntu server.So long as the internal address of the router is in the same address range of the client computers that you indicated in `pg_hba.conf` this should be easy to set up, otherwise add a new entry in `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: thank you very much, this is a very good and well structured answer. I would like to know more about setting a NAT rule "to point traffic on port 5432 to the IP of your Ubuntu server". I have thomson gateway, is it enough to set protocol to: "Any", trigger range to "5432-5432", and leave Translate to ... empty, trigger protocol empty and trigger port empty?

Comment: I followed your guidelines step by step and now it works perfectly for a local network. You might also want to add to your answer that ubuntu firewall has to be disabled with "sudo ufw disable" in order to get everything working. (more complicated approach is to edit iptables)

Comment: @Vekszor Glad to be of help. On the issue of the Thompson gateway, I have no experience with that one but there are many sites on the web that have specific details for every router and gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comments to the correct answer: 
This is how you add a rule to iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

0/0: If you want anybody to access it. 
You can change it to a specific ip address or range of ip addresses.

Comment: still cannot believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to the server using UI you can run the below query to get the IP Address of server using below query to verify if you are using the correct IP.

```
Select inet_server_addr();
```